# Editing security setting of a folder through code

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-permissions

I am trying to attach my SQL Server Databases to instance of the server through code.  It gives an error that the folder that contains these files does not have 'Full Control' that I need to give by right clicking on the folder, and editing the Securities.

I wish to do it through code.  Please advise if it is possible using Netsh command or any other way.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use xCacls to change NTFS permissions ...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754

"xcacls file name [/T] [/E] [/C] [/G user:perm;spec] [/R user] [/P user:perm;spec [...]] [/D user [...]] [/Y]

where file name indicates the name of the file or folder to which the ACL or access control entry (ACE) is typically applied. All standard wildcard characters can be used. "

The link above gives the rest of the syntax and a couple of examples.